# Poco C++ NetworkInterface crashes on Android

Tags: c++, c++11, android-ndk, android-5.0-lollipop, poco-libraries

This line of code works fine on Windows:

```
NetworkInterface::NetworkInterfaceList nicList = NetworkInterface::list();
```

But crashes immediately with the following exception on Android:

```
A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 20506 (Thread-2479)
```

The only related information I could find were several mentions that starting with Lollipop Android will kill your app immediately if it tries to perform any Networking functions on the MainActivity UI thread.

Since I run this code on its own thread, the SIGABRT must be related to something inside the call made to NetworkInterface::list()?

Comment: you can add some log to determine which lines on earth cause crash.  You can go into thie list function , use __android_log_print to print the message